# ACF Nested Realationship Meta Query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro, meta-query

Custom Post Types:

`vendor`
`solution`
`appointment`

Each appointment has a relationship field `vendor_solution` that's connected a `vendor` to an appointment. A user is attached to a `vendor` by way of a user_vendor custom field.

I need to be able to get all `appointment` for the currently logged in user and I'm having a hard time construction the correct `WP_Query` to do so. I know this requires a nested meta_query, but this has always confused me.

User:

- user_vendor

Solution:

- vendor

Appointment:

- vendor_solution

Again, I need all `appointment` for the currently logged in user. The user makes the connection to the `vendor`

Comment: how is the user attached to the meta? via custom post type or usermeta?

Comment: Hi, maybe I miss something, but, why don't you "simply" add a direct relation between a user (client I guess) and an appointment? Appointment should hold a reference of each party involved no?